# Is there a functional n:1 bimap?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, frege, bimap

I have a map where multiple keys can map to the same value. I'd like to do reverse lookups, such that given a value, I get a list of all keys that map to this value. 
Note that unlike 
[`Data.Bimap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bimap) my map is not 1:1 but *n* :1.

Also, the reverse lookup should not take *O(n)* like running through all map entries would require but rather *O(log n)* or better like with a reverse index. The map will contain many ten-thousands of entries with a high load of add/remove/lookup operations.

Is such a data structure available in functional form (Haskell or Frege preferred)?

Comment: The linked code is just a wrapper around two maps. Why not make a wrapper around a map and a multimap?

Comment: And if you really only have O(100,000) entries and need speed on add/remove/lookup, you should probably use `data N1Bimap a b = N1Bimap !(HashMap a b) !(HashMap b (HashSet a))` for some added speed, if your fundamental types are `Hashable`. (You can automatically derive `Hashable` in GHC, too.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm afraid this is not as efficient as I hoped for since every add/remove in the first map will not only cause a change in the reverse map but a rundown through its value list in O(m) where m is the size of the reverse lookup result size.

Comment: @Dierk: That is why you then use a set/hashset data structure for the reverse map, to get O(log n + log m) removals.

Comment: Ok, yes, overlooked the HashSet. Thanks!

Comment: Even if you cannot hash, you can use Map b (Set a) instead of multimap for faster deletions.